# How to fix SQL syntax for this example?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

> The code should display the result of the LEFT JOIN of the 3 tables, but it is not and giving the error message attached below.

> Reactjs: The code fetches the values and displays it in console.log

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Axios from "axios";


export default function DisplaySell() {

      function sellfunc(){
        console.log("function call")
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getselldatatable').then((response) => {
           console.log("TABLE DATA",response)
        });
      }
    return (
        <div>
            here
            <button onClick={sellfunc}>Sell</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> Nodejs: The code fetches all the records from 3 different tables

```
let getsalessql = `SELECT * FROM sales where CustomerEmail=? AND SellSession=(select max(SellSession) from sales)`;
var idMedicineDatabase;
var EmailID;
app.get("/getselldatatable", (req, res) => {
    EmailID="test2@gmail.com";
            db.query(getsalessql,[EmailID],(err, result1) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(result1)
                        let getsalessql2 = "(SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase as m LEFT JOIN inventory as i ON m.idMedicineDatabase = i.idMedicineDatabase LEFT JOIN sales as s ON m.idMedicineDatabase = s.idMedicineDatabase) where m.idMedicineDatabase IN (${result1.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')})";
                        db.query(getsalessql2,(err, resultnew) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log(resultnew)
                                //console.log(resultnew)
                                res.json(resultnew)
                            }

                        });
                    
                }
          });
    
});
```

> MySQL Error Message

[image]

Comment: Please post the error message as text. If you read it while doing so, you might see the problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax in your SQL string...only you're using double-quotes, not the required backtick for template literals. Try this:

```
let getsalessql2 = `
  SELECT * 
  FROM medicinedatabase as m 
  LEFT JOIN inventory as i 
    ON m.idMedicineDatabase = i.idMedicineDatabase 
  LEFT JOIN sales as s 
    ON m.idMedicineDatabase = s.idMedicineDatabase 
  where m.idMedicineDatabase IN (
    ${result1.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}
  )`;
```

Using anything other than backticks, the `${result1.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')}` won't be replaced the way you probably intend.

*Edit: as @strawberry mentions in comment, the parentheses around the `select...from` clauses in your original query shouldn't really be there...I've removed them.

*Edit2: template literals allow multi-line strings; indenting SQL for readability.

Comment: `s.idMedicineDatabase) where` Tell us about this closing parentheses. What is it doing?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, good catch; I didn't really look too closely at the OP's query once I noticed the `${...}` in the error message. All I did was copy the query and change the quotes to backticks. I've now edited my answer to remove the errant parens from OP's query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post this under the question; the perils of posting from phone